# DataFrame values Changing after adding columns using withColumn

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, scala-spark

I have created a dataframe by reading the data from db2 and dataframe looks like below.

```
df1.show()


Table_Name | Source_count | Target_Count
----------------------------------------
Test_tab   |  12750       | 12750
```

After that, I have added 4 columns with values hardcoded using `withcolumn` lit. after adding these columns count was changed.

```
df2 = df1.withColumn("").withColumn("").withColumn("").withColumn("")

df2.show()
```

| Table_Name | Source_count | Target_Count | batch | source | test_type | Record_ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test_tab | 12600 | 12750 | -1 | p1 | count | 2022-05-12 20:20:15 |

I didn't understand why this happens. df2 was created immediately after df1.

Can someone explain what are the possibilities for this change?

Comment: Did you type your code correctly? You have `df` in your first snippet, but `df2` is built from `df1`.

Comment: yes it is df1 not df.

Comment: Is your `df1` calculated from another data or read directrly from files also if you can add `df2.explain()` to your question

Comment: df2.show() is another action that executed on underlying files. it seems underlying files might changed. Did you retry to run df1.show()?

Comment: Thank you...

df2 = df1

df2=df2.withColumn().....

df2.show()

i did this and working fine.